# Differentiable affine transformation on patches of images in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, affinetransform

I have a tensor of object bounding boxes, e.g. with the shape of [10,4] which correspond to a batch of images e.g. with shape [2,3,64,64] and transformation matrices for each object with shape [10,6] and a vector that defines which object index belongs to which image.
I would like to apply the affine transformations on patches of the images and replace those patches after applying the transformations. I am doing this using a for loop now, but the way I am doing it is not differntiable (I get the in place operation error from pytorch). I wanted to know if there is a differntiable way to do this. e.g. via grid_sample?

Here is my current code:

```
for obj_num in range(obj_vecs.shape[0]): #batch_size
    im_id = obj_to_img[obj_num]
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = boxes_pred[obj_num]
    im_patch = img[im_id, :, x1:x2, y1:y2]
    im_patch = im_patch[None, :, :, :]
    img[im_id, :, x1:x2, y1:y2] = self.VITAE.stn(im_patch, theta_mean[obj_num], inverse=False)[0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to perform differentiable crops in PyTorch.

Let's take a minimal example in 2D:

```
>>> x1, y1, x2, y2 = torch.randint(0, 9, (4,))
(tensor(7), tensor(3), tensor(5), tensor(6))

>>> x = torch.randint(0, 100, (9,9), dtype=float, requires_grad=True)
tensor([[18., 34., 28., 41.,  1., 14., 77., 75., 23.],
        [62., 33., 64., 41., 16., 70., 47., 45., 19.],
        [20., 69.,  5., 51.,  1., 16., 20., 63., 52.],
        [51., 25.,  8., 30., 40., 67., 41., 27., 33.],
        [36.,  6., 95., 53., 69., 84., 51., 42., 71.],
        [46., 72., 88., 82., 71., 75., 86., 36., 15.],
        [66., 19., 58., 50., 91., 28.,  7., 83.,  4.],
        [94., 50., 34., 34., 92., 45., 48., 97., 76.],
        [80., 34., 19., 13., 77., 77., 51., 15., 13.]], dtype=torch.float64,
       requires_grad=True)
```

Given `x1`, `x2` (resp. `y1`, `y2` the patch index boundaries on the height dimension (resp. width dimension). You can get the grid of coordinates corresponding do you patch using a combination of [`torch.arange`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.arange.html) and [`torch.meshgrid`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.meshgrid.html):

```
>>> sorted_range = lambda a, b: torch.arange(a, b) if b >= a else torch.arange(b, a)
>>> xi, yi = sorted_range(x1, x2), sorted_range(y1, y2)
(tensor([3, 4, 5, 6]), tensor([5]))

>>> i, j = torch.meshgrid(xi, yi)
(tensor([[3],
         [4],
         [5],
         [6]]), 
 tensor([[5],
         [5],
         [5],
         [5]]))
```

---

With that setup, you can extract and replace patches of `x`.

1. You can extract the patch by indexing `x` directly:

   ```
   >>> patch = x[i, j].reshape(len(xi), len(yi))
   tensor([[67.],
           [84.],
           [75.],
           [28.]], dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<ViewBackward>)
   ```

   Here is the mask for illustration purposes:

   ```
   tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=torch.float64,
   grad_fn=<IndexPutBackward>)
   ```
2. You can replace the values in `x` with the result from some transformation on the patch using [`torch.Tensor.index_put`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.index_put_.html#torch.Tensor.index_put_):

   ```
   >>> values = 2*patch
    tensor([[134.],
            [168.],
            [150.],
            [ 56.]], dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<MulBackward0>)

   >>> x.index_put(indices=(i, j), values=values)
   tensor([[ 18.,  34.,  28.,  41.,   1.,  14.,  77.,  75.,  23.],
           [ 62.,  33.,  64.,  41.,  16.,  70.,  47.,  45.,  19.],
           [ 20.,  69.,   5.,  51.,   1.,  16.,  20.,  63.,  52.],
           [ 51.,  25.,   8.,  30.,  40., 134.,  41.,  27.,  33.],
           [ 36.,   6.,  95.,  53.,  69., 168.,  51.,  42.,  71.],
           [ 46.,  72.,  88.,  82.,  71., 150.,  86.,  36.,  15.],
           [ 66.,  19.,  58.,  50.,  91.,  56.,   7.,  83.,   4.],
           [ 94.,  50.,  34.,  34.,  92.,  45.,  48.,  97.,  76.],
           [ 80.,  34.,  19.,  13.,  77.,  77.,  51.,  15.,  13.]],
       dtype=torch.float64, grad_fn=<IndexPutBackward>)
   ```

Comment: Thanks! cloning the im_patch before feeding it to STN worked though!